# Eliminate repeated 'user defined runtime attribute' code in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have many classes that all have a `borderColor` property.  I can set this property in the user defined attributes in the storyboard and then use a single `UIView` extension to actually add the border and it's color.  Works great.

But I have to declare 'borderColor' property in each subclass.  Neither protocol extensions nor a `UIView` extension will allow me to declare this kind of computed property just once so I can use it in all of my subclasses.

I have many other classes and many other properties like `borderWidth`, `shadowColor`, etc, so it ends up being a substantial amount of repeated code.

And each subclass needs to inherit from the specific super class, i.e. `UIImageView`, and not just `UIView` because there are other methods not detailed in the example below.  So I can't just add these to some `UIView` subclass and then have all these classes inherit from it.

Any thoughts on how I might reduce all the repeated properties in my project?

Thanks!

```
class BDRImageView: UIImageView {
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        willSet {
            if let color = newValue {
                addBorder(color: color)
            }
        }
    }
}

class BDRLabel: UILabel {
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        willSet {
            if let color = newValue {
                addBorder(color: color)
            }
        }
    }
}

class BDRButton: UIButton {
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        willSet {
            if let color = newValue {
                addBorder(color: color)
            }
        }
    }
}

//and so on...

extension UIView {
    func addBorder(color: UIColor) {
        //does add border stuff...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage Objective C runtime feature's associated objects to add custom properties to existing classes in categories

```
extension UIView {

    private struct customProperties {
        static var borderColor: UIColor = .clear
    }

    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self,
                                  &customProperties.borderColor) as?   UIColor
        }
        set {
           if let color = newValue {
                objc_setAssociatedObject(self,
                             &customProperties.borderColor,
                             color,
                             .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
               // Do whatever you want to do with color
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could reduce your code by declaring the computed properties in a protocol and then creating an extension of each subclass which adopts that protocol. For example, your current code could be reduced to:

```
protocol BorderColorSettable {}
extension BorderColorSettable where Self: UIView {
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            //you will have to supply something here
        }
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                self.addBorder(color: color)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension UIImageView: BorderColorSettable {}
extension UILabel: BorderColorSettable {}
extension UIButton: BorderColorSettable {}

extension UIView {
    func addBorder(color: UIColor) {
        //does add border stuff...
    }
}
```

You could even then put the implementation in the protocol to remove the `UIView` constraint

```
extension BorderColorSettable {
    var borderColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            //you will have to supply something here
        }
        set {
            if let color = newValue {
                self.addBorder(color: color)
            }
        }
    }

    func addBorder(color: UIColor) {
        //does add border stuff...
    }
}
```

The concept is basically this: declare a protocol with the functionality you want. Create an extension of an existing class (e.g. `UIImageView`) which does nothing more than adopt that protocol. This then provides all instances of UIImageView with that protocol's functionality.

If you give me a moment, I can go run this in a test project to ensure that it works out of the box. Otherwise you can try to adapt it in your own.

Edit: I've thrown this into a small project and it seems to work just fine. For example, after implementing all of that code, I am able to run some operations like this:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.addBorder(color: .black)
```

or

```
var label = UILabel()
label.borderColor = .black
```

Hopefully this meets your needs. Let me know if I can explain any part of it more thoroughly.

Comment: This is a great answer, I didn't know I could still use `get` and `set` in a protocol extension even though I can't use `willSet`.  But when I move the property to an extension it never gets called when setting the property through a user defined runtime attribute in the storyboard.

Comment: Hmm, I've never tried that. I'm not so familiar with exactly what is happening in the background when it comes to storyboard runtime attributes. This is interesting enough that I would like to look into it :) maybe I can get back with some useful information later @Frankie

Answer (score 0):

You can add your properties in an **objc** extension so that they compile in objc runtime and accessible from subclasses.

```
@objc extension UIView {
    var borderColor: UIColor {
        get { UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor ?? UIColor.clear.cgColor) }
        set { layer.borderColor = newValue.cgColor }
    }
}
```